# Ensure clean removal of apt sources without loss of security updates

Tags: apt, package-management

At the times of Debian Wheezy, I needed php 5.6, so I used [dotdeb](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) sources to get it. Now with Debian Jessie, apparently the [latest version of php is already 5.6](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/php5), so I don't need dotdeb anymore. I would like to remove it from my `sources.list`, but I'm afraid some other components are still using dotdeb for security updates. How can I ensure that nothing is using dotdeb anymore?

**The scenario I'm afraid of is**: Some package is using dotdeb for the last version, which is higher than the standard debian packages version. Now if I remove the dotdeb repository source link, and some security update gets released for the new dotdeb package, that means my software won't be updated, until standard debian packages become higher than whatever dotdeb provided before I removed it.

What's the right way to remove dotdeb sources list without bad consequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. comment out the dotdeb repositories;
2. run `apt-get update`;
3. run `apt-show-versions` (from the `apt-show-versions` package) and look for anything flagged "newer than version in archive" (that's the exact string used for packages newer than anything in the configured repositories).

You can then investigate the packages you found in the last step, if any, and decide whether to downgrade to the version in Jessie, or continue using the dotdeb repositories.